# Monaco editor in content script. "Define is not defined", "synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vs/editor/editor.api'."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, requirejs, monaco-editor

I'm trying to make it work in content script:

manifest.json

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js",
        "content.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js",
        "editor.js"
      ],
    }
]
```

content.js

```js
let root_path = chrome.runtime.getURL("")
require.config({
    paths: { vs: root_path + 'monaco-editor/min/vs' }
})
```

editor.js

```js
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
    init_monaco_editor(...)
})
```

Everything is okay, yet it doesn't support any language. Here's the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at markdown.js:7:1
```

I tried to add every language handler manually like this:

```json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js",
        "content.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js",
        ...
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/lua/lua.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/m3/m3.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/markdown/markdown.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/mips/mips.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/msdax/msdax.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/mysql/mysql.js",
        "monaco-editor/min/vs/basic-languages/objective-c/objective-c.js",
        ...
        "editor.js"
      ],
    }
]
```

Most of the languages started to work, but some of them (javascript, html, python) now produce an error of another kind:

```
Uncaught Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vs/editor/editor.api'. This module has not been resolved completely yet.
    at u.synchronousRequire (loader.js:1477:23)
    at u._relativeRequire (loader.js:1460:29)
    at r (loader.js:1636:30)
    at python.js:8:999
    at python.js:8:516
    at python.js:8:1097
    at python.js:8:4195
    at u._invokeFactory (loader.js:1188:41)
    at u.complete (loader.js:1198:36)
    at u._onModuleComplete (loader.js:1828:20)

Uncaught Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vs/editor/editor.api'. This module has not been resolved completely yet.
    at u.synchronousRequire (loader.js:1477:23)
    at u._relativeRequire (loader.js:1460:29)
    at r (loader.js:1636:30)
    at javascript.js:8:999
    at javascript.js:8:516
    at javascript.js:8:1097
    at javascript.js:8:6651
    at u._invokeFactory (loader.js:1188:41)
    at u.complete (loader.js:1198:36)
    at u._onModuleComplete (loader.js:1828:20)
```

I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just injected `editor.main` and the language files separately and it started to work:

content.js

```js
let root_path = chrome.runtime.getURL("")
require.config({
    paths: { vs: root_path + 'monaco-editor/min/vs' }
})

// (communicate with the background script to call `some_func`.)
```

background.js

```js
async function some_func(tab) {
    await injectFiles(tab.id, [
        'monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js',
        'monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js'])

    await injectFiles(tab.id, monaco_language_files) // everything from basic-languages folder
}

function injectFiles(id, files) {
    return chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
            target: { tabId: id },
            files: files,
            world: "ISOLATED"
        })
}
```

That's it, `require(['vs/editor/editor.main'])` is not needed anymore.